# PS4 Plus on two accounts

Tags: ps4

Ok so I just purchased a ps4 Slim and then got ps4 plus for one account, I have heard that multiple accounts can use the same ps4 Plus but on my PS4 it only has the icon for it on one account, any answers?

Comment: The icon will only appear on the account with the actual plus features, but the other accounts will have access to the free Plus games, for example, if the Plus user has activated the PS4 as their primary device.  (Check under settings)

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per HazyKingdom's comment.

Answer (score 1):

If one acount logged in on the PS4 has PS plus, then every account on that console can play online. It is not however possible to give other users access to your discounts, or other plus features.

Comment: I believe the console has to be marked as the account's primary PS4, as well.

Comment: Other accounts can play the account's games on its primary console.